# Image Upload Widget Issue

Tags: widgets

I'm trying to make basic image upload widget. The uploader is working, however a button **Save** is not active after selecting new image. There is a hidden input where the value of new image is updating. But even after the value updated, WordPress doesn't recognize it. Only if I manually edit this input, the Save button is activated.

So here is my PHP code:

```
  // setup the widget name, description etc.
  function __construct() {
    $widget_options = array(
      'classname'   => esc_attr( "widget-about text-center" ),
      'description'  => esc_html__( 'About me widget', 'lami' ),
      'customize_selective_refresh' => true
    );
    parent::__construct( 'lami_profile', 'Lami About Me', $widget_options);
  }


  // front-end display of widget
  function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    extract( $args );
    echo $args['before_widget'];

    if ( ! empty( $instance['image_url'] ) ) {
      $alt = get_post_meta( attachment_url_to_postid($instance['image_url']), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
      ?>
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $instance['image_url'] ); ?>" class="widget-about-img" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $alt ); ?>">
      <?php
    }


    echo $args['after_widget'];
  }


  // back-end display of widget
  function form( $instance ) {

    $instance = wp_parse_args(
      (array) $instance,
      array(
        'image_url' => '',
      )
    );

    $image = ( ! empty( $instance['image_url'] ) ? $instance['image_url'] : '' );

    ?>  


      <!-- Image -->
      <h4><?php esc_attr_e( "Choose your image", 'lami' ); ?></h4>
      <p>        
        <img class="deo-image-media" src="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" style="display: block; width: 100%;" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" class="deo-image-hidden-input widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image_url' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image_url' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" />
        <input type="button" class="deo-image-upload-button button button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Choose Image','lami')?>">
        <input type="button" class="deo-image-delete-button button" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Remove Image', 'lami') ?>">
      </p>


    <?php
  }


  // update of the widget
  function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['image_url'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['image_url'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['image_url'] ) : '';
  }

}


add_action( 'widgets_init', function() {
  register_widget( 'Lami_About_Widget' );
});
```

**And JS code for Uploader and Buttons**

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  /* WordPress Media Uploader
  -------------------------------------------------------*/
  function upload(type) {
    if ( mediaUploader ) {
      mediaUploader.open();
    }

    var mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Select an Image',
      button: {
        text: 'Use This Image'
      },
      multiple: false
    });

    mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
      var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
      $('.deo-' + type + '-hidden-input').attr('value', attachment.url);
      $('.deo-' + type + '-media').attr('src', attachment.url);
    });
    mediaUploader.open();
  }

  $('body').on('click', '.deo-image-upload-button', function() {
    upload('image');
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.deo-image-delete-button', function() {
    $('.deo-image-hidden-input').attr('value', '');
    $('.deo-image-media').attr('src', '');
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: By default, WordPress has an image uploader widget. Why do you need a custom one?

Comment: This widget will also contain textarea and checkbox fields. I cut down all the other fields for now, just to focus on image upload.

Comment: I would save only the id of the image and not the full url, unless you explicitly need to support external urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Updated`**

Actually, you have to trigger `change` event to activate the **Save** button. WordPress widget handler listens to only changes. When you update the input field value with JS, DOM doesn't trigger any `change`. That's why we have to trigger manually. Please check the following code -

```
$('.deo-' + type + '-hidden-input').val(attachment.url).trigger('change');
```

Comment: That was my previous code. But it didn't work.

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: That's amazing, thanks a lot for the help! I've spent almost all day figuring out what's wrong :)

Comment: That's great, glad to hear that it saved your time.